# How to grant Hyper-V VM management to specific users?

Tags: permissions, hyper-v

I want to grant non-admin users the privilege to start/stop/checkpoint specific VMs.

The [Grant-VMConnectAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/grant-vmconnectaccess?view=windowsserver2022-ps&viewFallbackFrom=win10-ps) cmdlet should do the job. I also added the user to the *Remote Management Users* group.

But when trying to connect to the VM I get a .NET exception in the windows event log:

```
Application: vmconnect.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException
   at Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Internal.Operations.CimSyncEnumeratorBase`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.Server.LoadOSInfo()
   at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.ConnectionHelper.ConnectServer(Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.InformationDisplayer, System.String, Boolean, Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Common.IUserPassCredential)
   at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.ConnectionHelper.TryGetVirtualMachinesInternal(System.String, Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Common.WindowsCredential, Mode, System.String, System.Guid, Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.IVMComputerSystem ByRef, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.String> ByRef, System.Exception ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.ConnectionHelper.TryGetVirtualMachine(System.String, Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Common.WindowsCredential, System.String, Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.IVMComputerSystem ByRef, System.Exception ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.InteractiveSession.CommandLineParser.TryParse(System.String[], Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.InteractiveSession.RdpConnectionInfo ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.InteractiveSession.VmisApplicationContext.TryParseCommandLine(System.String[])
   at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.InteractiveSession.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

vmconnect.exe did only work if I also put the user into *Hyper-V Administrators* or *Administrators* group. But this gives the user full access to all the VMs.

**Update**: I want to get it working on Microsoft Hyper-V Server 10.0.17763  Build 17763. But I also couldn't get it working on Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0.17763 Build 17763

Comment: vmconnect.exe did only work if I also put the user into Hyper-V Administrators or Administrators group. But this gives the user full access to all the VMs   ..  I believe that is the way Hyper-V normally works, at least on my system here.

Comment: What is your Windows Server version ?

Comment: @harrymc I updated the question with the requested infos.

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote, why my question was not clear or did not show some research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for role-based access control for Hyper-V,
for which you need to install
[System Center Virtual Machine Manager (VMM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/vmm/overview?view=sc-vmm-2019).

To learn more about the subject see the Microsoft article
[Manage roles and permissions in VMM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/vmm/manage-account?view=sc-vmm-2022).

You face a learning-curve, but lots of helpful material can be found on
the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll give it a try and will provide feedback.